# EditText in ListView - changing focus of EditText

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a view, which contains a ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/products_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Every row has some image, text and an EditText.
I achived the functionality of gaining/loosing focus in EditTexts, but I have problem, when I enter the view, and click some EditText. Always the first click on any EditText changes the focus from the one clicked, to the first in the list.

My holder for that view has implemented methods:

```
    @Override
    public void bindValues(CatalogsProducts item) {
        note.addTextChangedListener(this);
        note.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(v instanceof EditText && !hasFocus) {
            if(item != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(note.getText().toString())) {
                item.setCertainNote(note.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        item.setCertainNote(s.toString());
    }
```

Any ideas how to not loose focus from the first clicked EditText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In layout XML :

```
<ListView  
    android:id="@+id/products_list"      
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    />
```

In Mainfest.xml:

```
<activity android:name= ".yourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Hope this help you !!

Comment: it works - thx.
But is there any way, to keep the functionality of resized view and without loosing focus on clicked item?